# The Sum of Predictions Is Equal To The Prediction Of the Sum?

Tags: probability, statistics

As the title states, I think it is valid only for linear models, doesn't it?
Consider, predictions of $P_i=\hat{P}_i+\epsilon_i$. Then, the predictions of $S=\sum_iP_i=\hat{S}+\gamma_i$. The question is: $\hat{S}\equiv\sum_i\hat{P}_i$ ?

From an expectation point of view:

$\mathrm{E}[S]=\sum_i\mathrm{E}[\hat{P_i}+\epsilon_i]=\sum_i\mathrm{E}[\hat{P_i}]+\sum_i{\mathrm{E}[\epsilon_i]}$

In other words, in order to predict the values of $S$, shall I sum $P_i$ then predict the next value of this sum, or shall I make predictions on every single $P_i$ and then sum $\hat{P_i}$ ?
Is the question elementary?

Comment: This question as stated is a bit too vague, but note that [Linearity of Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) holds _even if_ the random variables (e.g. here, the error terms?) are _dependent._

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is still unclear, but here is what you can say:

- Regardless of the dependence relation between the various variables, linearity of expectation **always** holds.  So:

$$E[\hat{S}]+E[\gamma] = E[S]=\sum_i E[\hat{P_i}+\epsilon_i]=\sum_i E[\hat{P_i}]+\sum_i E[\epsilon_i] $$

- If you know that $E[\epsilon_i] = E[\gamma] =0$, then you can further conclude $E[\hat{S}]= \sum_i E[\hat{P_i}]$
- I don't know what you mean by $\hat{S} \equiv \sum_i \hat{P_i}$.  If you mean they are always equal, then no you cannot conclude that.  Under the second bullet's precondition you can conclude they have equal expectations.
- As to the question of "shall I do this or shall I do that", I have no idea.  :)  I don't even know what you're trying to achieve / optimize.

Comment: I meant your 3rd point . Thank you. I needed to know if the prediction of the aggregate converge in probability to the sum of single predictions.

Comment: With the info you gave so far, you cannot conclude that the aggregate converges to the sum.  However, if you have additional info, esp. _how_ you do the prediction, it might be possible.  (In that case it's perhaps a result of the prediction _algorithm_.)

Comment: the problem is that indeed: which algorithm to use in order to make the minimum prediction error